# Images don't Show up when Website's Live

Tags: image, file, upload, hyperlink, dns

I have created a website whereupon the images (like social media icons) work perfectly on my computer and local host, but now I have uploaded them to my actual website, only the images referenced in javascript- the background images. Any suggestions?

Here's the site: www.finmoorhouse.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i can nearly guarantee your paths are incorrect... View the source in Chrome or Firefox, and try to click the link to where the image should reside.

Answer (score 1):

You have bad referenced the images/folders

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.finmoorhouse.com/Icons/flat/Twitter.png"
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.finmoorhouse.com/overlays/12.png"

The problem is that you have folders in upper case on the website, and referenced in lower case
try this

> finmoorhouse.com/Icons/Flat/Twitter.png

Comment: Ok, so we have ascertained that the links are dodgy. How do I fix this?

Comment: I recomend you to not use upper case in files directory, problems like this appear all time

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise case was an issue in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled the Hotlink Protection?

If you enabled it, you should turn off Hotlink Protection to be sure if it is not the case.

follow this link
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/HotLinkProtection